# vba:save the result xml file to certain path

Tags: xml, vba

I write a script below:

```
...
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("XXXX.xml", True)

a.write......

a.close
```

I want to save the xml file "a" - xxxx.xml to a specified path. I search the functions of "Scripting.FileSystemObject", there should be a method to choose the save path.

But I haven't found the answer after trying. anybody knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add the path to the filename:

```
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\XXXX.xml", True)
```